# Effective repartee for "It's for your own safety"

Tags: rhetoric

We've heard this subversive phrase all too often but I've yet to come across a good reply.

- How would you categorize this device and
- Acknowledging that context is important, what kind of rhetorical defense would you use.

Comment: Since you acknowledge the importance of context, I think some would be useful. Could you give an example of a scenario and a conversation?  It can only be categorised as a device if it is unnecessary.   For example: "Don't stand on the edge of the cliff--I'm saying that for your own safety."  would simply be good advice.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a question about English.

Comment: I suspect that the rhetorical defense would be highly contingent on context. Perhaps with a few examples, we could prove/disprove that suspicion.

Comment: "Infantilization is not a solution" ?

Comment: Not as individuals, but collectively as a society we are being told by the UK  government that they need to have access to our internet browsing records for one year. And it is ***for our own safety***.

Comment: The intent is not to cover special cases but to expose blanket use of this deceptively framed coercion. Perhaps a good strategy would be to attack the patronizing angle or revert the argument in asking who's going to protect you from the protector.

Comment: Why don’t you let *me* worry about my own safety.

Comment: Well, in most cases the statement really means "It's for our convenience", but I don't think knowing that helps much.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a grain of truth to the statement, but the restriction is assinine rather than sensible, then it is an extreme example of **Nanny-statism**:

> **Nanny state** is a term of British origin that conveys a view that a government or its policies are overprotective or interfering unduly with personal choice. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanny_state)

The -ism refers to an attitude/behavioural practive that infects authoritarians beyond the state itself.

Suggested response: "No, it's for the safety of morons, and as I am not one, I won't allow undue consideration for imbeciles to constrain my freedom thank you very much!" [...*Potentially famous last words*]

If the motive is actually something completely different - *eg* your actions, if proceeded with, could be detrimental not to your own safety, but to some other interest entirely - then really this is just an example of **deception**. Which could start to be unravelled with the response: "Really? How so?"

Comment: +1 for the questioning response. Talking about authoritarianism... now they don't even allow new users to upvote answers. Not to speak of closing the question with vague arguments - who's "too broad" here?